# how to check/print psycopg2 dynamic query Compose without creating conn.cursor()

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest, psycopg2

I am writing unit test for a query builder, in which I assemble query from a couple of user input fields.

e.g.

```
 query = sql.SQL("SELECT {fields} FROM {table}).format(
                                fields='*'
                                table=sql.Identifier(topic)))
```

I just wanna check if the query is what I desired, no need to execute.

I was trying to print query, and got a composed object which looks like

```
Composed([SQL('SELECT '), Composed([Identifier('*')]), SQL(' FROM '), Identifier('topic'), SQL(' '), SQL(''), SQL(' ')...)
```

Is there a try to transform the dynamic sql as a Composed object to a sql query String?

```
SELECT * FROM topic
```

I don't have the postgres set up for the unit test, so I cannot use

```
query.as_string(conn)
```

Any hints? Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`cursor.mogrify(query, params)`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify), but to call it you need a cursor and to create a cursor you need to open a connection. I don't believe you can get the final query without a connection; this is because the query depends on server and database (server version, database encoding, quoting style).

Comment: thanks!... eventually decide to start a local postgres server with docker.